# What are the most frequently used Dominion cards in winning decks?

Tags: dominion, statistics

Which cards are most bought by players, and most often associated with winning decks?

Comment: Gold, and Province since they are in every game. I any guessing you want to adjust for frequency though.

Comment: Colony (when in play), Platinum (when in play), Province, Gold, Chapel... (I'm at work and can't check, but I'd have to guess Bishop as the next card on the list)

Answer (score 9):

[councilroom.com](http://councilroom.com) hosts stats for millions of online games played at [dominion.isotropic.org](http://dominion.isotropic.org).

It's currently down but it should give you the most accurate answer when it goes back up again.

For example, here is a [ranking of the best openings](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3apXRICOKWFAYJ%3acouncilroom.com/openings?card=All%2bcards%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk) from google's cache

Comment: Gets fresh internet connection, in first 5 minutes, he reads bg.se, sees post about councilroom being down. I should stop slacking ;)

Answer (score 6):

The card that immediately pops to mind:

[image: Chapel]

[Here's an article](http://dominionstrategy.com/2010/11/17/dominion-chapel/) on dominionstrategy.com which outlines why this card is considered the best in the game. No other card allows you to shape your deck so quickly and early, ensuring you get useful and powerful draws to ramp up your deck.

If you look at the best openings ranking linked by Dor Shemer, you'll see many openings at the top of the list that include Chapel.